# How to make a plot with repeating labels on X axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As a result of the previous code, I have two lists.
How can I make a plot with letters from "lab" (one by one) on the X-axis, and corresponding numbers from list `val` - on the Y axis?

I tried:

```
lab = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
val = [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.bar(lab, val)
```

It plots each letter only once.
[image]
And I want it to plot the whole sequence letter by letter.

Comment: You should tag `matplotlib` as this is related to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexes, and then just set the xticks labels like:

```
lab = ['G', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'C', 'A', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'R', 'G', 'C', 'N']
lab_x = [i for i in range(len(lab))]
val = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.bar(lab_x, val)
plt.xticks(lab_x, lab)
```

Comment: You can just do `plt.bar(range(len(lab)), val)`. No need to use additional for loop and list comprehension and `lab_x`

Comment: Thank you for help! I applied the previous variant and it worked.