# Repeated Categorical X-Axis Labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have a simple question: **why are my x-axis labels repeated?**

[image: MWE Plot]

Here's an MWE: [**X-Axis Labels MWE**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yJHJdqIiZkkG9yZntyLWywKJNKY60nWU?usp=sharing)

```
a = { # DATA -- 'CATEGORY': (VALUE, ERROR) 
      'Cats': (1, 0.105), 
      'Dogs': (2, 0.023), 
      'Pigs': (2.6, 0.134)
     }

compositions = list(a.keys()) # MAKE INTO LIST

a_vals = [i[0] for i in a.values()] # EXTRACT VALUES
a_errors = [i[1] for i in a.values()] # EXTRACT ERRORS

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6)) # DICTATE FIGURE SIZE   
bax = brokenaxes(ylims=((0,1.5), (1.7, 3)), hspace = 0.05) # BREAK AXES 
bax.plot(compositions, a_vals, marker = 'o') # PLOT DATA

for i in range(0, len(a_errors)): # PLOT ALL ERROR BARS
  bax.errorbar(i, a_vals[i], yerr = a_errors[i], capsize = 5, fmt = 'red') # FORMAT ERROR BAR
```

Here's stuff I tried:

- [Manually setting x-axis tick marks using `xticks`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388670/how-to-make-a-plot-with-repeating-labels-on-x-axis)
- [Converting strings to floats using `np.asarray(x, float)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/ticks_too_many.html)
- [Reducing # ticks using `pyplot.locator_params(nbins=3)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/reducing-number-of-plot-ticks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=len(compositions))` to reduce the number of x-ticks so that it matches the length of `compositions`.

More on `locator_params()` method, which controls the behavior of major tick locators:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.locator_params.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

a = {  # DATA -- 'CATEGORY': (VALUE, ERROR)
    'Cats': (1, 0.105),
    'Dogs': (2, 0.023),
    'Pigs': (2.6, 0.134)
}

compositions = list(a.keys())  # MAKE INTO LIST

a_vals = [i[0] for i in a.values()]  # EXTRACT VALUES
a_errors = [i[1] for i in a.values()]  # EXTRACT ERRORS

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))  # DICTATE FIGURE SIZE
bax = brokenaxes(ylims=((0, 1.5), (1.7, 3)), hspace=0.05)  # BREAK AXES
bax.plot(compositions, a_vals, marker='o')  # PLOT DATA

for i in range(0, len(a_errors)):  # PLOT ALL ERROR BARS
    bax.errorbar(i, a_vals[i], yerr=a_errors[i], capsize=5, fmt='red')  # FORMAT ERROR BAR
    
bax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=len(compositions))

plt.show()
```

#### Result:

[image]